# Pedagogue vs. pedagogy vs. pedagogical

Tags: pronunciation, orthography

How do people choose to pronounce the *-agogue* suffix in these three words?

> 1. [pedagogue](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/pedagogue)
> 2. pedagogy
> 3. pedagogical

The first is a reasonably common word and its suffix is surely consistently pronounced as `/əgɒg/` (*agog*). However, dictionaries suggest that the relevant bits of the other two words can be alternatively pronounced either as `/əgɒdʒi/`/`/əgäji/` (*agoji*), or as `/agɒgi/` (*agogi*). In other words, while people always use a *hard g* for the first *g*, they might prefer a *soft g* for the second.

The same can be noted for pronunciations of the various forms of [demagogue](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/demagogue) and [synagogue](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/synagogue). Why this "discrepancy"? How do people decide to choose the hard or soft *g* for **such uncommon words**? It might be *cough* logical to conclude that people who choose the *soft g* do so due to their familiarity with the French-influenced *-logy* suffix. However, I personally pronounce *pedagogical* with a *hard g* due to my preceding use of another *hard g*.

Or is this simply an AmE-BrE divide?

Comment: It is a question of *analogy*. The soft g is standard in *-logy* and *-logic* and *-logical*, and regular (palatalized before front vowels). I'd bet moreover that most of those words were established before the corresponding terms in *-og*, *-ogue* entered the language, probably mostly as back-formations. They're at least far more common  - how many times have you read of a *geologue* or a *neurolog*?!

Comment: @StoneyB But none of those examples have a _g_ following another, i.e., _gog_. My question is on the inconsistency of the pronunciations.

Comment: Only the first has *-agogue*; the others have *-agogy* and *-agogical*, so this does not make sense. I still do not understand what sound `/ä/` is intended to represent.  A centralized `/a/`?  That’s not a phoneme in English, and is at most an allophone of some phoneme. Hey, you aren’t [Australian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPA_chart_for_English_dialects), are you?

Comment: Well, here are some more - mostly new coinages, but *anagogy* and *apagogy* and *mystagogy* at least have been around for awhile. And in any case, the analogical palatalization operates only the 'g' before 'y' or 'i'.

Comment: @tchrist It's possible that _Crocodile Dundee_ had a bigger impact on America than first thought. The `/ä/` was lifted right out of ODO (AmE) :)

Answer (score 3):

With all the words you mention, the normal rule applies.  Barring some sort of exception, then, whenever the *g* is followed by an *e*, *i*, or *y*, one follows the standard pronunciation rule that it is pronounced like the *j* in *jet* (`/dʒ/`), not like the *g* in *get* (`/g/`).

It is also true that once upon a time, long ago and far away, words like *hypnagogic* at one point ***did*** once have a hard *g* there.  Same thing with words like *œsophageal/oesophageal/esophageal*.

But not even physicians do that any longer.  People will think you’ve made a mistake if you use a `/g/` instead of a `/dʒ/` in words like those.

Comment: +1 And the older words, which established the pattern, came into English not directly from Greek but through Latin, which had palatalized the 'g' even before it reached Old French.

Comment: hmm, I see. Yet ODO lists the _hard g_ variant as an acceptable alternative. How about the OED? (I find the use of the soft _g_ quite unsettling in words such as _pedagogy_ and _pedagogism_.)

Comment: @coleopterist For *pedagogic* and *hypnagogic*, the OED  gives only the so-called soft-g sound. For *pedagogy* is admits a hard-g as the final of three alternatives.  For *pedagogism*, it says you must have meant to spell it *pedagoguism*. :)   The *gu-* makes it hard. Similarly with words like *synagoguing* and *pedagoguish*. Oh drat, you just made me discover that *caccagogue* and *copragogue* are words!

Comment: @tchrist jeje! I fell through the same rabbit hole and ran into _galactagogue_ and _ochlagogue_.